# Adding wmts layer to mapbox gl from geoserver

Tags: mapbox, geoserver, wms

I'm trying to add wmts layer from geoserver 2.18. My code:

```js
            window.mymap.addSource(
                "mvt-test-source", {
                 "type": "vector",
                "tiles": [
                    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&layer=mapbox:roads4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}"
                    ],
                "minZoom": 0,
                "maxZoom": 14
            });

            window.mymap.addLayer(
                {
                    'id': 'my_mvt_layer',
                    'type': 'line',
                    'source': 'mvt-test-source',
                    'source-layer': 'mapbox:roads4326',
                    "visibility": "visible",
                    'paint': {
                        'line-color': 'Red',
                        'line-width': 7
                    }
                }
            );
```

There are no errors in browser, but layer don't appear on the map.
What could be the reason?
When I try to use wms service - all work fine. Next code with wms format:

```js
window.mymap.addSource("wms-test-source", {
                "type": 'raster',

                "tiles": [
                  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:900913&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=mapbox:roads4326"
                ],
                'tileSize': 256
            });

            window.mymap.addLayer(
                {
                    "id": 'wms-test-layer',
                    "type": 'raster',
                    "source": 'wms-test-source',
                    "paint": {
                    }
                }                
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `visibility` property should not be added that way. Add  it like so:

```
 window.mymap.addLayer(
                {
                    'id': 'my_mvt_layer',
                    'type': 'line',
                    'source': 'mvt-test-source',
                    'source-layer': 'mapbox:roads4326',
                    'layout':{
                     "visibility": "visible",
                    }
                    'paint': {
                        'line-color': 'Red',
                        'line-width': 7
                    }
                }
            );
```